# Creating a MSG using MsgKit - how to use AddProperty-method?

Tags: outlook, mapi, msg, msgkit

I am using this tool
https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit
to create a MSG-file, then display and send it with Outlook.

I need to add the property "BillingInformation", so that after sending, an OutlookAddin is able to process the information.

I know, there is a method "AddProperty" - but i am not able to do this properly.

Can anyone help me? THX!

```
        using (var email = new Email( 
            new Sender(SenderTextBox.Text, string.Empty),
            SubjectTextBox.Text, 
            DraftMessageCheckBox.Checked,
            ReadReceiptCheckBox.Checked)) 
        {
            email.Recipients.AddTo(ToTextBox.Text);
            email.Subject = SubjectTextBox.Text;
            email.BodyText = TextBodyTextBox.Text;
            email.Attachments.Add("Images\\peterpan.jpg");

            email.AddProperty(??????, "abcd");
  
            email.Save("c:\\temp\\email.msg");
                     }
  
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\temp\\email.msg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MsgKit, but looking at its source code, what you need is something like the following

```
var billingPropTag = new NamedPropertyTag(0x8535, "Billing", 
                          new Guid("00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
                          PropertyType.UNICODE)
email.AddProperty(billingPropTag , "abcd");
```

You can see property tags (named and fixed) with the their tags, GUIDs and ids using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click IMessage button or open an MSG file by clicking OpenIMsgOnIStg:

[image]

Comment: var billingPropTag = new NamedPropertyTag(0x8535, "Billing", new Guid("00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), PropertyType.PT_UNICODE);
produces an CS0122 error and i have no idea, how to handle this ...

Comment: That happens because `NamedPropertyTag` is an internal class...

Comment: Without actually compiling it, I think your only option is to modify the library (it is open source) and add the Billing property. You can then modify the Save method to set that property when saving.

Comment: thank you - for me as a beginner this is unfortunately too complicated for me :-( why is there an AddProperty method if it is not usable? is there any other way to reach my  need?

Comment: would it be possible with Redemption, to create a msg-file (including BillingInformation) from a template-msg-file without connection to outlook and then load the file into outlook like above?

Comment: Yes, of course. If Outlook is installed (Redemption needs the MAPI system), you can use `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile / RDOMail.BillingInformation = "abcd" / RDOMail.Save` to do that.

Comment: could it be that this only works if my programm connects to the OutlookApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT?

Comment: `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile` does not require an active MAPI session.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new MSGKit package. I never realised that this was a named property not a normal one.

[image]